# Immediate XCode crash (Swift 2.2)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I got something like this :

```
specialized _ContiguousArrayBuffer._checkValidSubscript(Int) -> () [inlined].
```

When i try debug my code , print description of my Array or item that i put into ,  my XCode closes.

Crash details :

```
System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        24  <DBGLLDBSessionThread (pid=666)>  Dispatch queue: DVTInvalidationPreventionQueue

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
```

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I was trying to use property on `nil` object

```
for trip: Trip in tripArray {
    NSLog("\(trip.hotel.name)") // hotel == nil
}
```